# HTML PHP redirect submit form to same page with error message

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating a submit contact form. However when the submit button is pressed with incorrect informations, i want it to go back to my contact.php page with an additional error message at the top of the body page such as. "We are very sorry, there were errors found with the form you submitted, these errors appear below:
Incorrect Email
Incomplete Last name" etc

i have two files, contact.php for form and send_form_email.php for email process

in my contact file, i have below code;

```
$inc = $_GET['inc'];
if($inc ==1) {
            echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
            echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";}
    ?>
```

And in my send_form_email.php, i have following code

```
function died($error) {
    header("location: contact.php?inc=1"); 
    die();
}

if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
    !isset($_POST['email']) ||
    !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
    !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);}
```

however, when i entered incorrect name, the error message would not appear.

Can you please kindly help me ?

Regards, Lex

Comment: What is `died`?  Could be what's going wrong.  See example code here:  http://ideone.com/CZp0pz

Comment: echo $error."<br /><br />"; >> this code is not working in contact.php.the rest are working.

Comment: What name are you testing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to use `$_GET`. If so, you can do something like:

```
if($_GET['inc'] ==1)
```

Comment: Hi, apology, i have added the code mention above, however $error still not working.